# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems

Tags: java, colors

this is my Errorcode:

```
Exception in thread "main" : 
TextAttributes cannot be resolved to a type
TextAttributes cannot be resolved to a type
Console cannot be resolved to a type

    at Font.main(Font.java:8)

import java.awt.Color;
import enigma.console.*;
import enigma.core.Enigma;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TextAttributes attrs = new TextAttributes(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE);
        s_console.setTextAttributes(attrs);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
    private static final Console s_console;
    static
    {
        s_console = Enigma.getConsole("Hellow World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to import a relevant class in your code.

Comment: could you say which one it is? :/

Comment: `TextAttributes` is not imported either is not listed in imported packages. The same is for `Console` class.

Comment: looking at the code line, it is probably the TextAttributes which you have not importd. If you ar on eclipse, do a Ctrl+shit+o which will organize your imports.

Comment: TextAttributes and Console, as the error message indicates. Don't try to execute code until you have fixed ALL the errors displayed in the "Problems" view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pay attention to the comments, they are wrong. The problem is not in your imports, it's in your environment. If you run your code in an IDE, try to clean your environment.
I just tried to compile and run your code in a console, it works fine.